# Please suggest some great websites for a .NET programmer

Tags: .net

I'm new to world of .NET programming and I want to know about websites that have articles, tips and other useful information about .NET and Microsoft technologies. The websites I currently visit are:

- MSDN
- StackOverflow
- WindowsClient.NET
- TheServerSide.NET

I'd love to learn about some new .NET websites!

Comment: Aren't these sites enough? What have you needed that they don't supply?

Comment: I listed some blogs relevant to ASP.nET MVC below:

 http://www.codetoglory.com/?p=59

Comment: @John These site have a lot of information but sometime I have found that it have another article, tips and technique that don't have on these site on other website. (may be I can't find it.)

Sorry if this question annoy you. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [PDC site](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/) has a bunch of great
  videos (changes ever year).
- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) is MS's open source
  project host.
- You have MSDN, but [Patterns &
  Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) is a great place to
  check out.
- [Events @ MS](http://www.microsoft.com/events/webcasts/ondemand.mspx) for on demand web
  casts.
- MSDN [Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570323.aspx) are fantastic.
- [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) is an awesome resource
  for everything MS.
- [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/) has tons of great
  blogs.  Including the [master's blog](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/dbox/).
- [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) has great videos,
  interviews, etc.
- [Chris Sells site](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/) is cool.
- Tons of great [sessions from
  Mix09](http://live.visitmix.com/).
- [WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/)
- [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/)
- [Enterprise Patterns](http://martinfowler.com/articles/enterprisePatterns.html) (Fowler)
- [Data & Object Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx)
- [Architecture Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/bb410935.aspx)
- [Google's Microsoft search page](http://www.google.com/microsoft.html)
- [Dictionary of Algorithms](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/) (not
  .net specific, but great still)

I just found:  ["How do I?" videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb629407.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Good blogs about C#/.Net:

- Jon Skeet: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx
- Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/default.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Lots of good resources already listed.

If you're looking for articles, [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) is a good site to frequent.

Answer (score 5):

[silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net)

[Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com)

[Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com)

[dnrTV](http://www.dnrtv.com)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try and read [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) as often as possible to keep yourself updated in the .Net world

Answer (score 2):

Good pocasts:
[dotnetrocks.com](http://dotnetrocks.com/)
[dnrtv.com](http://dnrtv.com/)
[www.hanselminutes.com](http://www.hanselminutes.com/)

And some blogs:
[weblogs.asp.net/scottgu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu)
[www.lhotka.net/weblog](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog)
[haacked.com](http://haacked.com)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some that may help you get started:

- [C Sharp Course](http://www.csharpcourse.com/)
- [C Sharp Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/C_Sharp_Essentials)
- [C Sharp School Book](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/csharpbook)

The following is not web based resources, but something you may want to consider:

- If you can afford it, look on Amazon for a book on .NET, look at review stars to determine which ones are good.
- Look at [C# Design Patterns - James W Cooper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201844532) for an understanding of the GOF patterns in C#

Don't be afraid to visit [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) and search for an application that maybe what you are interested in and download the source code.

Run the application in debug mode to understand how it works. You can also do a [Google Search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=open+%2B+source+%2B+c%23) for open source C# projects to further increase your learning.

Good luck on your learning

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in performance, see Maoni's blog to know how the GC works

http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetKicks](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/) is a nice aggregation of various .NET-related blog posts and other news.  It's not geared specifically for new users, but there is definitely a lot of useful content on many topics.  It's also rather timely, so I've found it to be a good resource for staying on top of the latest technologies and discussions in the .NET world.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free C# documentation, just for the basics:

[Galileo Openbook - Visual C# 2008](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/visual_csharp/)

For me, it's mostly [google.com](http://www.google.com) to start with :-)

Comment: Is there an English language version of this page?

Answer (score 1):

Only advanced (or quirky) ASP.Net, C# and SQL Server stuff
http://blog.DigitalTools.com

Answer (score -3):

I would say there are more bad ones than there are good ones.

:(

Personally I usually stick to MSDN and read the official blogs/posts from the product teams.

Comment: That may be true, but with the number of blogs available that still leaves plenty of room of many good ones.

Comment: Hmm... the fact that there are many bad websites is all the more reason to actually list the good ones.

Comment: @tylerl I agree, just making a comment that there is a ton of bad stuff :( I'm eager to find good stuff so will recheck this thread