# Programming and Design related Podcasts

Tags: podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there)

What are the useful podcasts sites that should be followed for programming or design related topics? Or to catchup on the latest technologies ?

Any useful links will be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there

Comment: Check out [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780198/please-suggest-some-great-websites-for-a-net-programmer/780302#780302) ... not specific to podcasts, but plenty of good audio & video resources there.

Comment: This is pretty much a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there. If you are looking for design specific podcast please re-word this or ask a separate question

Comment: Closing this one out since you haven't gotten any unique answers in 24 days.  The other post linked has a **ton** of good resources, so I hope you found what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of 
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html

Actually all of IT Conversations is great

Answer (score 0):

DotNetRocks - http://www.dotnetrocks.com/

Hanselminutes - http://www.hanselminutes.com/